# AS3 Mobile Splash Screen Sound

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, audio, splash-screen

Creating a project using AS3, have my splash screen files set up. Curious to know if it's possible to play a sound while the splash screen is up?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which part you need help on? You should be able to easily create a new Sound object when you initialize your screen. Typically I create a SoundManager class to handle all application sounds when starting a new project.

Comment: Yes.   Show your code for your splash screen and someone will show you some code to play a sound on it.

Comment: MPO is it's better to avoid using ActionScript in loading/splash screen graphics, because if you don't know what you're doing, you can wind up dragging all the Classes and potentially all the assets used by the project ahead of frame 1, which defeats the purpose of having a splash screen/loader. IOW, use timeline sounds instead. Try setting it to stream.

Comment: I'm using Flash Builder to develop the project... as far as I know all I do is put in the .png's with the right name and dimensions and it displays as a splash screen, I don't have any code for it.